# Access image in GCP Artifact Registry from Gitlab CI/CD using a service-account key

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to run a Gitlab CI job using an image from a private GCP Artifact Registry, i.e.:

```
build job:
  stage: build_job
  image: toto-tata-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp/my-project/my-image:${IMAGE_VERSION}
  variables:
    ...
```

I have read in many places, including in [GitLab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#access-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry) that using a `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` CI/CD variable could do the trick, and it is suggested to use

```
docker login toto-tata-docker.pkg.dev --username my_username --password my_password
```

and copy whatever is in `~/.docker/config.json` after that.

Now my problem is that I am using a service account to authenticate into that AR, and I have no idea how to find the username and password necessary to generate the "right" `~/.docker/config.json`.... :'(

I tried using a Credential Helper as suggested in GCP doc (that is actually what my `~/.docker/config.json` looks like on my laptop when I `docker login` with the service account key):

```
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "toto-tata-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud",
  }
}
```

but the job fails because of a denied permission:

```
...
denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on reso
...
```

It would be awesome if anyone could advise !!

Thank you !!